# Iterator for loop in map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, c++14

I tried the following code but i am not able to find the error. The error is in the loop section but I can not figure out that how to correctly use the iterator in order to avoid the errors. **Please help** and please clarify my concepts.
The problem statement is https://codeforces.com/contest/268/problem/A. I have solved it via vector

```cpp
    int main()
    {
        std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
        int n,x,y,count=0; cin>>n;
        std::vector<pair<int,int>> v;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            cin>>x>>y;
            v.push_back(make_pair(x,y));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j=i+1; j < n; ++j)
            {
                if(v[i].f==v[j].s){
                    count++;
                }
                if(v[i].s==v[j].f){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<count;


        return 0;
    }
```

but having problem via map.
It gives SIGTSTP error when using map.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::make_pair;

int main() {
  std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
  int n, x, y, count = 0;
  cin >> n;
  std::map<int, int> m;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> x >> y;
    m.insert(make_pair(x, y));
  }

  for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i) {
    for (auto j = ++i; j != m.end(); ++j) {
      if (i->first == j->second) {
        count++;
      }
      if (i->second == j->first) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << count;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Please add any error message or unexpected output (with corresponding input) to your question. Click [edit] to do so.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385174/5910058)

Comment: What's the purpose of the program?

Comment: You're double-incrementing `i`. I mean, `++i` will always execute after each *outer* loop iteration, *and* on each inner loop initial setup.That means you can eventually land `i` on `m.end()` with the inner-loop init, *then* attempt to bump it further on the increment step of the next outer-loop iteration (which happens *before* the comparison test), That bump-past-end invokes UB. I *suspect* changing the inner-loop init setup to `auto j = std::next(i)` will do what you seek, but without explaining the overall purpose of your code, that's a complete crystal-ball guess.

Comment: I have added the relevant information, please check and help.

Comment: The edit section has become so weird now. ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use map data structure for this problem because map store elements in a mapped fashion. Each element has a key value and a mapped value. **No two mapped values can have same key values.**
But according to the question, the key values can be same, so thats why you cannot use map here.
For more details you can see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Using multimap  and std::next(i,1) in the loop solved the problem. Can anyone tell that when solving these type of  problems, what should we be using vector<pair<int,int>> or map/multimap?

Comment: If it is guaranteed that the key of the map is unique then use map otherwise vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

const int N = 50;

int h[N], a[N];

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d%d", h + i, a + i);
  }

  int ans = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      if (i != j) {
        if (h[i] == a[j]) ans++;
      }
  printf("%d\n", ans);
  return 0;
}
```

The answer to the problem is `sigma { h[i] = a[j] } (i != j)`.

Your code has made these mistakes:

1. `std::map::insert` means set certain key to certain value. Plus, `std::map` is different from `std::multimap`. The latter allows the existence multiple same keys while the former doesn't.
2. You shouldn't just make the starting point of `j` as `i + 1` since the iteration range should be `[0, i - 1]` union `[i + 1, n - 1]` (edit: your code's logic is right as well).
3. Iterator cannot be so rashly self incremented because it has side effects as the comment section points out.

Comment: When solving these type of  problems, what should we be using vector<pair<int,int>> or map/multimap or something else?

Comment: A normal array is sufficient for many cases. Use `std::vector` when you need features like `push_back`.

Comment: Algo contest is all about quick and correct answers. So don't use techniques that make no boost to the answer and drag your coding speed (just like the additional log N that `std::map`/`std::multimap` takes).